# Multuiprocessing not executing a function properly in python 3

Tags: python, multiprocessing, process.start

When using the `.start()` method to execute a function, the function doesn't work as I expected. I can see that the line `time.sleep()`works, but changing the variable and print statement does. The functions executes when the `.run()` method is called, but this runs the code in series to other functions and not multiprocessing.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
import sys

worker1 = None
worker2 = None


def worker():
    time.sleep(60)
    worker1 = 6
    print("hello")
    sys.stdout.flush()

def workertwo():
    time.sleep(60)
    worker2 = 6
    print("world")
    sys.stdout.flush()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello = Process(target=worker)
    world = Process(target=workertwo)
    world.start()
    hello.start()
    world.join()
    hello.join()
    print(worker1)
    print(worker2)
```

This is just a test piece of code that shares the problem with a larger software. I'm running on a windows 10 machine, running python 3.6.8

when I run this code I get:

```
None
None
>>>
```

but I would expect to get:

```
hello
world
6
6
>>>
```

Its being ran from a script file but does work when being ran from inside the command prompt. It will be running alongside a tkinter GUI so would need to run from the script (I assume)

This is my first question on here, and I'm self-taught. Any guidance would be helpful,

thanks Danny

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Note, your assignment statements here simply create local variables, which cease to exist after the function terminates, and have no connection to the global variables with the same name... In general, when asking a question, **don't make us guess**. Saying "it doesn't work" *is not an adequate problem description*. *what doesn't work and how?*

Comment: its the .start() function of the module that I don't think works, the worker function only has the time line run, where as the lines that change the variable and the print statement don't run, the only print out I get into the shell is None and None

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to share a global variable between multiple processes which obviously doesn't work. Possible options for sharing variables in memory between processes are described here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Value
import time
import sys


worker1 = Value('i', 0)
worker2 = Value('i', 0)


def worker(worker1):
    time.sleep(3)
    worker1.value = 6
    print("hello")
    sys.stdout.flush()

def workertwo(worker2):
    time.sleep(3)
    worker2.value = 6
    print("world")
    sys.stdout.flush()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello = Process(target=worker, args=(worker1,))
    world = Process(target=workertwo, args=(worker2,))
    world.start()
    hello.start()
    world.join()
    hello.join()
    print(worker1.value)
    print(worker2.value)
```

OUT:

```
world
hello
6
6
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have just copied and pasted your code and run it on my machine and have just got the 6 and 6 printed to the shell, but the hello and world print statements still don't. please can you tell me what vison of python are you running, thanks

Comment: Are you by any chance running this code in a notebook? If yes, then that is an expected behavior for IPython runtime. To get the same result as I got you need to run it under regular python. My python version is 3.6

Comment: im running python 3.6 on a custom built PC